# How to insert and retrieve Android code on this Firebase structure?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am from PHP and MySQL background and I haven't worked with JSON based DB like Firebase.

I am looking for sample code to insert data in firebase "Realtime database". I am already done with authentication stage.

[image]

Comment: Hey @PanjabWeb do mark the answer as correct by clicking on V type tick mark looking button next to the answer, this helps the future stack overflow readers with similar questions and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

To insert some data in your Firebase Database, you have to set the reference to the node you want to insert the data to and then use `setValue()` method.

Suppose you want to change `age` of the `admins` node, in your database in the question.

In code it looks something like this:

```java
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("admins");

ref.child("age").setValue(76);
```

The above code will replace 42 with 76, in your `admins` node's `age` child.

[Read more about this here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)

Getting data from Firebase Database is a bit more work, as you have to use listeners for that. There are 3 different event listeners at your disposal, that are `valueEventListener` `childEventListener` and `singleValueEventListener`.

These three `eventListeners` have different properties and you can use them as you like.

Suppose you want to retrieve `age` of your `admins` node from your database, then you may use a code like this to help. Note `ref` in this code is same as in above code.

```java
ref.addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        int age = dataSnapshot.child("age").getValue(String.class);
        // this will store value of age from database to the variable age

    }

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    // Failed to read value
    Log.d("TAG:", "Couldn't read data ", error.toException());
}
});
```

[Read more about this here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Comment: What if I don't use user at first level? how to register users within first level separately  admins, members and helpers while using createUserWithEmailAndPassword  


   mydb
      |
      admin
          |
          .... id: xast3241fdpa
          |
          ... name : john

Comment: Then just don't use `.child("users")` and just push data to Firebase just with the specific child name like `admins` and `members`.

Comment: Hey @PanjabWeb do vote up and mark the answer as correct by clicking on V type tick mark looking button next to the answer, this helps the future stack overflow readers with similar questions and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link, https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Write a message to the database

```
// Write a message to the database
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

Read a message from the database

```
// Read from the database
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
    }

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    // Failed to read value
    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
}
});
```